# Django load static in development directly from static folder (Not from apps)

Tags: django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

I use django for the backend, in the frontend I use vue.js, so 99% of my CSS it's handled by vue.js, however I need a simple `base.css` for some customization in the landingpage and few things like this.

Normally in django I would put the file inside `app/static/app/base.css` then do collectstatic and get it under `static/app/` for production.

I would like to avoid to keep it under an app as it's just a file. I'm trying adding a folder under my main "static" folder. But it seems in development django in not fetching it at all, it fetches directly and only static files from apps.

How can I tell django to fetch it directly from the `static` main folder as it would do in production?

i.e. I want to add a folder called `main` in my root (where manage.py is) and use only that to store my static files for both production and development, without passing through the single apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell Django to look for static files in other directories by using [`STATICFILES_DIRS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATICFILES_DIRS) settings.

Just add the following code in your settings.py and it should work:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
```

Comment: But then I get: `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should not contain the STATIC_ROOT setting`

Comment: @Costantin `STATIC_ROOT` and `STATICFILES_DIRS` shouldn't be the same. If you want Django to render static files from your project's `static` dir, specify it using `STATICFILES_DIRS` (like in this answer). The `STATIC_ROOT` settings mean where you want to collect your static files.

Comment: Now everything works like this:
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "..", "assets")
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "..", "static"),
]
However the folder assets doesn't even exists. I guess django will create it if I run collect statics, but I probably don't ever need it. Can I completely remove the whole STATIC_ROOT?

Comment: @Costantin In production, you'll be probably serving your static files via Nginx (or another server). You've to map the `/static/` url in the server config to your `assests` directory so that your server can find all the files there. I think you do need the `assests` folder. But if you've configured your server in another way, then it all depends on you.